# Jquery jheartbeat - want to stop the process

Tags: jquery, function

Using the following JS script.
It works great but I want the ability to stop the process and can not figure out how to achieve this.

```
$.jheartbeat = {
options: {
    url: "heartbeat_default.asp",
    delay: 10000
},
beatfunction:  function(){},
timeoutobj:  {
    id: -1
},
set: function(options, onbeatfunction) {
    if (this.timeoutobj.id > -1) {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutobj);
    }
    if (options) {
        $.extend(this.options, options);
    }
    if (onbeatfunction) {
        this.beatfunction = onbeatfunction;
    }

    this.timeoutobj.id = setTimeout("$.jheartbeat.beat();", this.options.delay);
},

beat: function() {
    $("#HeartBeatDIV").load(this.options.url);
    this.timeoutobj.id = setTimeout("$.jheartbeat.beat();", this.options.delay);
    this.beatfunction();
}
```

};

Would like to be able to add a function to Kill the heartbeat or stop the process calling the backend page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.timeoutobj.id` is the variable the timeout is being assigned to, yet you are trying to clear `clearTimeout(this.timeoutobj);`.  You're targeting the wrong variable.

The clear should be `clearTimeout(this.timeoutobj.id)`, and that would be the same operation you would do in your kill method.

Comment: This solved that issue - but I do have another ask...  If I wanted to modify the delay option - how could I do that through jquery

Comment: The way you have it structured it looks like you could provide the delay on the options passed to `set()`, or change it directly with `$.jheartbeat.options.delay` as you have it exposed. @MatthewFriedman